# Dte.Commands.Execute: File.NewProjectFromTemplate

Tags: visual-studio, envdte

I want to create a new projet from an existing template in Visual Studio 2017.
I am using the following code:

```
dte.ExecuteCommand("File.NewProjectFromTemplate", WhatDoIPassHere);
```

If I pass no parameter, it returns: "The operation could not be completed"

If I pass any string: "This command needs a single parameter that contains 10 pipe-separated parts"

I tried to create a string and I've got: "Could not find template with ID xxx".

Any helps?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually used that command personally. But from what I can see in the info that you've supplied, I'd guess:

- that the string value that you passed wasn't a valid **id** of an existing template
- that if you pass nothing that the select template dialog might appear

Were you trying to open a particular template?

If so you'd need to provide the **id** of the template (which might not be the 'name' of it)?

If not then you should be able to just omit the second parameter.

Comment: In Visual Studio StartPage, we can click in some templates.
I want to open one of them programmatically.
I cant figure out the 'name' of the template.

Comment: @Wilsade I don't know how to find out their names either, but if you ask in the `extendvs` Gitter room, someone there may be able to help you